ZkSync contract deploy error execution reverted (unknown custom error)
I am trying to make a multisig contract account on zksync. Here is my AAFactory.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {DEPLOYER_SYSTEM_CONTRACT} from "@matterlabs/zksync-contracts/l2/system-contracts/Constants.sol";
import {SystemContractsCaller} from "@matterlabs/zksync-contracts/l2/system-contracts/libraries/SystemContractsCaller.sol";
import {IContractDeployer} from "@matterlabs/zksync-contracts/l2/system-contracts/interfaces/IContractDeployer.sol";

contract AAFactory {
    error AAFactory__AccountDeployerFailed();

    bytes32 public aaBytecodeHash;

    constructor(bytes32 _aaBytecodeHash) {
        aaBytecodeHash = _aaBytecodeHash;
    }

    function deployAccount(
        bytes32 _salt,
        address _owner1,
        address _owner2
    ) external returns (address accountAddress) {
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = SystemContractsCaller
            .systemCallWithReturndata(
                uint32(gasleft()),
                address(DEPLOYER_SYSTEM_CONTRACT),
                uint128(0),
                abi.encodeCall(
                    IContractDeployer.create2Account,
                    (
                        _salt,
                        aaBytecodeHash,
                        abi.encode(_owner1, _owner2),
                        IContractDeployer.AccountAbstractionVersion.Version1
                    )
                )
            );

        if (!success) {
            revert AAFactory__AccountDeployerFailed();
        }

        (accountAddress) = abi.decode(returnData, (address));
    }
}


aaBytecodeHash is the bytecode of MultisigAA.sol
I deployed the AAFactory successfully.
But when I deploy the multisig , I get an error saying execution reverted (unknown custom error)
Here is my multissig deployment script-
const hre = require("hardhat")
const { Wallet, utils, Provider } = require("zksync-ethers")
const addresses = require("../address.json")
const { Deployer } = require("@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy")

const AA_FACTORY_ADDRESS = addresses[hre.network.config.chainId]

module.exports = async () => {
    const provider = new Provider(hre.userConfig.networks.zkSyncTestnet.url)
    const wallet = new Wallet(process.env.RICH_ACCOUNTS_PRIVATE_KEY, provider)
    
    const factoryArtifact = await hre.artifacts.readArtifact("AAFactory")
    const aaFactory = new hre.ethers.Contract(
        AA_FACTORY_ADDRESS,
        factoryArtifact.abi,
        wallet
    )
    
    const owner1 = Wallet.createRandom()
    const owner2 = Wallet.createRandom()
    
    const salt = hre.ethers.ZeroHash;

    const tx = await aaFactory.deployAccount(
        salt,
        owner1.address,
        owner2.address,
    )
    await tx.wait()
    
    const abiCoder = new hre.ethers.AbiCoder()
    const multisigAddress = utils.create2Address(
        AA_FACTORY_ADDRESS,
        await aaFactory.aaBytecodeHash(),
        salt,
        abiCoder.encode(['address', 'address'], [owner1.address, owner2.address])
    )

    console.log(`Multisig account deployed on address ${multisigAddress}`)
}

The error comes from the aaFactory.deployAccount function.
The error-
Error: execution reverted (unknown custom error) (action="estimateGas", data="0xb0591126", reason=null, transaction={ "data": "0x76fb8b65000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000087f2d1d29b19486b0ea15131f1a2be0755f402fc000000000000000000000000dc3c0ddd0c52857dc41b55072c1132f57712a7e5", "from": "0xBC989fDe9e54cAd2aB4392Af6dF60f04873A033A", "to": "0xa85a2DFAe6bead4f408Fcc6EB8a3ec6C7AaCE9Eb" }, invocation=null, revert=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.13.1)
    at makeError (/home/i-atiq/projects/blockchain/zksyncAccountAbstraction/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:694:21)
    at getBuiltinCallException (/home/i-atiq/projects/blockchain/zksyncAccountAbstraction/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/abi/abi-coder.ts:118:21)
    at Function.getBuiltinCallException (/home/i-atiq/projects/blockchain/zksyncAccountAbstraction/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/abi/abi-coder.ts:235:16)
    at Provider.getRpcError (/home/i-atiq/projects/blockchain/zksyncAccountAbstraction/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/providers/provider-jsonrpc.ts:989:32)
    at /home/i-atiq/projects/blockchain/zksyncAccountAbstraction/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/providers/provider-jsonrpc.ts:563:45
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  action: 'estimateGas',
  data: '0xb0591126',
  reason: null,
  transaction: {
    to: '0xa85a2DFAe6bead4f408Fcc6EB8a3ec6C7AaCE9Eb',
    data: '0x76fb8b65000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000087f2d1d29b19486b0ea15131f1a2be0755f402fc000000000000000000000000dc3c0ddd0c52857dc41b55072c1132f57712a7e5',
    from: '0xBC989fDe9e54cAd2aB4392Af6dF60f04873A033A'
  },
  invocation: null,
  revert: null,
  shortMessage: 'execution reverted (unknown custom error)',
  info: {
    error: {
      code: 3,
      message: 'execution reverted: Error function_selector = 0xb0591126, data = 0xb0591126',
      data: '0xb0591126'
    },
    payload: {
      method: 'eth_estimateGas',
      params: [Array],
      id: 4,
      jsonrpc: '2.0'
    }
  }
}

I tried with a override like this-
const salt = hre.ethers.ZeroHash;
    const override = {
        gasLimit: BigInt("20000000")
    }
    const tx = await aaFactory.deployAccount(
        salt,
        owner1.address,
        owner2.address,
        override
    )
    await tx.wait()

But I get this error after that-
code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  action: 'sendTransaction',
  data: null,
  reason: null,
  invocation: null,
  revert: null,
  transaction: {
    to: '0x8df4285274DE8b19F4153f59f1881e29498F09E6',
    from: '0xBC989fDe9e54cAd2aB4392Af6dF60f04873A033A',
    data: ''
  },
  receipt: TransactionReceipt {
    provider: Provider { _contractAddresses: {} },
    to: '0x8df4285274DE8b19F4153f59f1881e29498F09E6',
    from: '0xBC989fDe9e54cAd2aB4392Af6dF60f04873A033A',
    contractAddress: null,
    hash: '0xb013cf63959841aff1bff832b902fafa08eb0b2004b58e6d7ebbdb5f26c901ae',
    index: 0,
    blockHash: '0x56c41a1c77b395ba4656d9ea865150086fb6c1a64dfd8af8feee49c6690621a1',
    blockNumber: 73,
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    gasUsed: 1019975n,
    blobGasUsed: undefined,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 0n,
    gasPrice: 25000000n,
    blobGasPrice: undefined,
    type: 0,
    status: 0,
    root: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    l1BatchNumber: 37,
    l1BatchTxIndex: undefined,
    l2ToL1Logs: []
  },
  shortMessage: 'transaction execution reverted'
}

My hardhat.config.js-
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy");
require("@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc");
require("@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-ethers");
require("@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-node")
require("dotenv").config()

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  zksolc: {
    version: "latest",
    compilerSource: "binary",
    settings: {
      enableEraVMExtensions: false,
      forceEVMLA: false,
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: '3',
        fallback_to_optimizing_for_size: false,
      },
    },
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.20",
    eraVersion: "1.0.0",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    }
  },
  deployerAccounts: {
    'zkTestnet': 0,
    dafault: 0,
  },
  defaultNetwork: "zkSyncTestnet",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      zksync: true,
    },
    zkSyncTestnet: {
      url: "http://localhost:8011",
      ethNetwork: "http://localhost:8545",
      zksync: true,
      chainId: 260
    },
    /* zkSyncTestnet: {
      url: "https://sepolia.era.zksync.dev",
      ethNetwork: "sepolia",
      zksync: true,
    }, */
    /* sepolia: {
      url: process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URl,
      accounts: [process.env.SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 11155111,
      timeout: 30000,
      blockConfirmations: 6,
      zksync: false
    } */
  },
  gasReporter: {
    enabled: true,
    currency: 'USD',
    //outputFile: 'gas-reporter.txt',
    coinmarketcap: process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY
  },
};


I am using local zksync node

You should modify deploy AAfactory script to:
const factory = await deployer.deploy(
    factoryArtifact,
    [bytecodeHash],
    "create",
    undefined,
    [
      aaArtifact.bytecode,
    ],);


Thanks, it's working now
